CSS Hover States that Affect Multiple Elements (Tailwind)
I'm trying to achieve a hover effect that does two things: when hovering over the image assigned .feature-image, I want the image to saturate and zoom (without expanding beyond original frame) while below it a paragraph, assigned .hidden-text slides out from below the h3 line under the image.
In the current code, the .hidden-text paragraph slides out when I hover over the h3 line, but not when I hover over the image. Naturally, I've tried to have the image, h3, and p all in one column, but then the image expands on the y-axis on hover, getting too close / covering the h3 line. So perhaps it may be easier to simply figure out how to contain the scaling in the original frame.
What is the correct way of setting up the image, h3, and p as an area that responds correctly on hover, or alternatively, to set up relations between classes that achieve the same effect? Is this something that Tailwind can facilitate, or is it better to stick to pure CSS?


console.clear();
@import url("https://use.typekit.net/poz1xqv.css");
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Syne:wght@400..800&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&display=swap') h2,
h3 {
  .syne-font
}

p {
  .work-sans-light
}

.syne-font {
  font-family: "Syne", sans-serif;
  font-optical-sizing: auto;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
}

.work-sans-light {
  font-family: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
  font-optical-sizing: auto;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
}

.hidden-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(-120%);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.feature-image:hover~.hidden-text,
.hidden-text:hover {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}
<div class="max-w-[1440px] mx-0 py-12 bg-greybg"><img class="w-screen mx-0 object-cover overflow-hidden" src="https://danverstg.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/Hero.jpg" alt="Trades Hero Image" /></div>

<div class="max-w-[1440px] mx-0 py-12">
  <div class="w-full grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 gap-20">
    <div class="max-w-[440px]"></div>
    <div class="max-w-[440px]">
      <h2 class="syne-font">We love working with our partners</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="max-w-[440px]">
      <p class="work-sans-light">Our partnership program is designed to help you provide great outdoor kitchen solutions for your clients.</p>
      <p class="work-sans-light pt-6">Learn about our products, get access to our brochures &amp; marketing materials, attend our training sessions.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="max-w-[1440px] mx-0">
  <div class="w-full grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 gap-20">
    <div class="max-w-[430px] items-left overflow-hidden">
      <img class="feature-image overflow-hidden object-cover saturate-0 hover:saturate-100 hover:scale-105 transition-all duration-500" src="https://danverstg.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/img1.jpg" alt="Feature Image 1" />
    </div>
    <div class="max-w-[430px] items-center overflow-hidden">
      <img class="overflow-hidden object-cover saturate-0 hover:saturate-100 hover:scale-105 transition-all duration-500" src="https://danverstg.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/img2.jpg" alt="Feature Image 2" />
    </div>
    <div class="max-w-[430px] items-right overflow-hidden">
      <img class="overflow-hidden object-cover saturate-0 hover:saturate-100 hover:scale-105 transition-all duration-500" src="https://danverstg.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/img3.jpg" alt="Feature Image 3" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="max-w-[1440px] mx-0">
  <div class="w-full grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 gap-20">
    <div class="max-w-[430px] items-left overflow-hidden">
      <h3 class="syne-font">Get to know our product</h3>
      <p class="hidden-text work-sans-light pt-8">We’ll help you gain a deep understanding of Danver’s products and processes, as well as our catalogs, libraries, and support team</p>
    </div>
    <div class="max-w-[430px] items-center overflow-hidden">
      <h3 class="syne-font">Training & info sessions</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="max-w-[430px] items-right overflow-hidden">
      <h3 class="syne-font">Builder pricing privileges</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>




With your current markup you would not be able to achieve what you want with CSS alone. With CSS you can target nested elements and sibling elements, but you cannot go UP the DOM tree. And with your current markup since the .feature-image and the .hidden-text are not nested together nor siblings it would not be possible. You would either need to change you markup or use javascript if you want to keep your markup
